# How to check if an attribute is present in Gatling/Scala

Tags: scala, gatling

I would think this is probably easy to do, but I really don't know Scala at all.

I have a scenario where a first time user will log in and see a page, then if they log in again they won't see this page. So the best I've come up with so far is this:

```
val chain = exec(
http("Login page")
  .get("/en/login")
  .headers(Config.HTML_HEADER)
).exec(
      http("login request")
        .post("/en/j_spring_security_check")
        .formParam("j_username", """${username}""")
        .formParam("j_password", """${password}""")
        .check(status.is(200))
        .check(currentLocationRegex(".*termsAndConditions").optional.saveAs("tc"))
    )
    .doIf(session => !session("tc").equals(null)) { // this doesn't work 
      exec(AgreeTermsAndConditions.chain)
  }
```

So I've tried a bunch of things on the doIf, the goal is just do if session "tc" is not set. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly read the [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/expression_el.html#expression-language): `${tc.exists()}`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually got it working doing session.conatins("tc"), but your way is better. I've updated that. I thought I had tried that actually, but guess I missed that in the docs.

Comment: The Gatling docs aren't the easiest to navigate and lack a lot of "big picture" context. A newcomer like myself would be hard pressed to know that the answer to a question about "doIf" lies in the "EL" page, and your answer doesn't provide that context either. Contrast your answer with Camilo Silva's to see what I mean. "Properly read the documentation" is unnecessarily confrontational.

Answer (score 3):

Gatling provides an `exists()` built-in EL function (see [Galting EL documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/#expression-language)), so a succincter solution would be:

```
.doIf("${tc.exists()}") {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked with:

```
.doIf(session => !session.contains("tc")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check with Nil instead. It works for me.